# Why pre-order traversal is favored for cloning a tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

I know the definition of pre-order traversal and want to understand why  pre-order traversal strategy is favored for cloning a tree ? I mean why it is preferred more than the other traversal mechanisms like in order traversal and post order traversals?

Comment: As a guess, because it's probably the easiest way to copy. An inorder traversal may require going up and down the tree too much, and a post order traversal is also not quite so efficient. So pre-order seems the most logical.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to build the children, you must have the parent (root) built also.
Pre-order is the only order that doesn't traverse through a child before passing its parent, unlike in-order and post-order which do.